# Roslyn CSharpCompilation with global implicit usings

Tags: roslyn, .net-6.0

Exists a way to tell CSharpCompilation.Create to use implicit usings?

[image: Net 6 project]

Comment: You can add file with `global using {namespaces}` import to the compilation and it should work.

Comment: Thanks you are right, the only thing to consider is that the global using list may vary depending on the project type as you can see here: https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2021/08/31/implicit-using-statements-in-net-6/

Answer (score 2):

The compiler doesn't know anything about `ImplicitUsings`, it's an SDK feature. As @Guru Stron mentioned in a comment, you can add a syntax tree with the global usings to the compilation you're creating. The list of global usings can indeed vary.

The global usings tree should ideally be in the form:

```cs
// <auto-generated/>
global using global::Namespace1;
global using global::Namespace2;
global using global::Namespace3;
```

The main set are:

```cs
// <auto-generated/>
global using global::System;
global using global::System.Collections.Generic;
global using global::System.IO;
global using global::System.Linq;
global using global::System.Net.Http;
global using global::System.Threading;
global using global::System.Threading.Tasks;
```

This list comes from https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/e797c37a264bf5b3a478baff0a085309228e0dea/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.CSharp.props#L25-L34

See also
https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/e797c37a264bf5b3a478baff0a085309228e0dea/src/WebSdk/Web/Sdk/Sdk.props#L64-L74
https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/e797c37a264bf5b3a478baff0a085309228e0dea/src/BlazorWasmSdk/Sdk/Sdk.props#L23-L27
https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/e797c37a264bf5b3a478baff0a085309228e0dea/src/WebSdk/Worker/Targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker.props#L41-L46